# How to change input field switch sequence (swithcing input field using Tab key) on a web page?

Tags: html, client-side-scripting, input-field

On a web page, if there are input fields, pressing Tab key switches them, but in a particular order, is there a way to change this order and set it to some different order?

If this can be done in html, it is preferable, but if some other scripting language (javascript etc) can do it, it is also acceptable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The attribute `tabindex` takes care of that http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H4.html
to exclude a element completely from the tabindex give it a index of `-1`
the lowest safe index to start with is `1`.

`0` is the default value so should be avoided when explicitly setting the `tabindex`

```
<input tabindex=1 type="text" name="my_input1">
<input tabindex=3 type="text" name="my_input2">
<input tabindex=2 type="text" name="my_input3">
```

The tab would go from the `my_input1` to `my_input3` to `my_input2` field in this example

tabindex may be used on `a`, `area`, `button`, `input`, `object`, `select` and `textarea`